# Не работают in-app purchases и restore на ios в production версии ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchases

В sandbox приложение работает как нужно. Однако, на prod версии не работает восстановление покупок и сами покупки. Список доступных продуктов загружается, содержит нужный нам продукт. Но при попытке рестора или покупки продукта возвращается ошибка Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".
Я проверила следуещее:

1. Продукт одобрен
2. Он привязан к проекту
3. Bundle id совпадает с  указанным в itunes connect
4. В настройках приложения покупки разрешены
5. В провиженах покупки добавлены
6. Прошла уже неделя после публикации в стор
7. Банковская информация вся заполнена, все соглашения подписаны.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Скажите пожалалуйста, вас удалось решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Аппл часто чудит. Так что на 100% ответить в чем проблем нельзя.
Я делал по данному туториалу. Попробуй сделать в той же последовательности, может поможет :)

http://alexanderyolkin.com/in-app-purchase-polnoe-rukovodstvo-1/

http://alexanderyolkin.com/in-app-purchase-polnoe-rukovodstvo-2/